# Error when trying to send FormData with jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

I have a file which I want to send to the server. The file is being passed within a FormData object and not as a path URI. This is the code I am using:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
formData.append('mode', 'fileInsert');
formData.append('conId', 'asdasd5535asf');
formData.append('user', 'user2422424');
formData.append('filesNumber', 1);
formData.append('msgType', 'fil');
formData.append('file0', file);

$.ajax({
    data: formData,
    success: function (a, s) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

When the code reaches the `$.ajax` call it throws this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

What is wrong? Note that the jQuery AJAX is being configured earlier, with post type, URL and such.

Comment: Try adding the following properties to the `$.ajax` call: `contentType: false, processData: false`

Comment: let me ask my server guy if anything is being received, it don't throw error now

Comment: It works, @RoryMcCrossan please give that as answer and explain what it does please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the following properties on your AJAX request:

```
contentType: false, 
processData: false
```

Setting `contentType` to `false` stops the `content-type` header being set. Similarly, setting `processData` to `false` will stop the content of the request being encoded, which is needed when sending a `FormData` object.

For more information on these and other `$.ajax` properties, see the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)